# How do you calculate a response for a create_fast handshake?

Tags: protocol

I'm reading through the specification and looking through the code (a slightly modified torpy), and I can't figure out what the `handshake_response` should be.

According to https://spec.torproject.org/tor-spec/create-created-cells.html#create_fast and
https://spec.torproject.org/tor-spec/setting-circuit-keys.html#kdf-tor, both the OP and the first hop generate random key material:

```
def handshake(self):
        return secrets.token_bytes(TOR_DIGEST_LEN)
```

and then the OP sends it X to the first hop, and the first hop responds with a `handshake_response` such that with it we can

```
def complete_handshake(self, handshake_response):
        # tor ref: fast_client_handshake
        peer_value = handshake_response[:TOR_DIGEST_LEN]
        key_hash = handshake_response[TOR_DIGEST_LEN:]
        shared_secret = self.handshake + peer_value
        computed_auth, key_material = kdf_tor(shared_secret)
        if computed_auth != key_hash:
            raise KeyAgreementError('Auth input does not match.')
        return key_material[:KeyAgreement.KEY_MATERIAL_LENGTH]
```

, where

```
def tor_digest(msg):
    return sha1(msg)


def kdf_tor(shared_secret):
    # tor ref: crypto_expand_key_material_TAP
    t = shared_secret + bytes([0])
    computed_auth = tor_digest(t)
    key_material = b''
    for i in trange(1, 5):
        t = shared_secret + bytes([i])
        tsh = tor_digest(t)
        key_material += tsh
    return computed_auth, key_material
```

So, how do we calculate the `handshake_response`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def calculate_handshake(X):
        Y = secrets.token_bytes(TOR_DIGEST_LEN)
        magic_second_part = kdf_tor(X+Y)[0]
        server_response = Y+magic_second_part
        print(f"the first hop is going to return handshake_response {server_response}")

        return server_response
```